# Display records for Core data 1:M relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

I'm sadly stuck with Core data. I've built a 1:M relationship, let's say Company and Employees.

I create the Company, then I create the Employee:

```
Employees *employee = (Employees *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employees" inManagedObjectContext:myObjectContext];

employee.name = employeeName;
employee.company = company;

NSError *error = nil;    
if (![myObjectContext save:&error])
{
    // Handle the error.
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error.description);
}
```

If I analyze the sql file, I can see that the Parent column for the Employees record is correctly populated with the Company identifier.
Now I would like to select a Company in my tableview and show its Employees in another tableview. I implement the `NSFetchedResultsController` as follows:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (fetchedResultsController != nil)
{
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

//retrieve context
if (myObjectContext == nil)
{
    id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    self.myObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription                                   entityForName:@"Employees" inManagedObjectContext:myObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *myFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:myObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
self.fetchedResultsController = myFetchedResultsController;
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

and I call it in viewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSError *error = nil;
//call the fetch
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Error with fetchedResultsController: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);
}
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

The problem is that all the Employees, and not only those in the selected Company, are displayed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fetch request is setup to fetch all employees with no condition so just as you are seeing, you are going to get all employees in your database. You either need to set a predicate on your fetch request using `NSPredicate` and have it only select Employees whose Company is the company you selected in the previous view. Or, the approach I would take, you have the Company object selected, pass its managedObjectId or the managedObject itself to your Employee tableview controller and use the relationship you setup to fetch the employees from it, Core Data will fill in any faults and fetch the related employee objects from the database for you.

If you setup your relationship properly calling `selectedCompany.employees` will return an NSSet which you can use as your `UITableViewController`'s data source.

**Edit**

If there are potentially a large number of employees in the relationship you may want to stick with the fetched results controller approach and setup the predicate appropriately in order to obtain the memory efficiency benefits that `NSFetchedResultsController` brings to the table.

Comment: I passed the ObjectContext and the Company object to the Employees View Controller, but I don't know how I can tell which Company was previously selected to the FetchedResultsController and show only the related Employees. Any suggestions please?
I've found that in this way:
`NSArray *a = [company.employees allObjects]; //employees is the relationship`

Is this the right way? Do this mean that in the Employees view controller I cannot use Core Data NSFetchedResultsController but I can only use an array with all the Employees?

Comment: Yes you can use it this way and this is the most simple way, this is what I meant by using the relationship. If you find yourself needing another NSFetchedResults controller you will need to set it up with an NSPredicate that only fetches employees for the selected company.

Comment: I understood, thanks...
But at this point, what about 1:1 relationships? For example, Employees and EmployeeDetails, one Employee has only one EmployeeDetail and viceversa.
How can I retrieve information about EmployeeDetail in EmployeeDetails view controller for the selected Employee?

Comment: If it is a relationship on the Employee object then the same way you got the employees on the contact object, access the property/attribute. This is one of the beauties of Core Data, once you have the NSManagedObject for your Entity you can access all the attributes on it and it will handle the fetches.

Comment: It wasn't easy but I finally got rid of it!
To retrieve data for a one-to-one relationship, it was enough the following:
`NSManagedObject *myDetails = employee.detail;`
Thank you very much, now I'm facing many-to-many relationships...

Comment: If you feel I've answered your question(s) I'd appreciate the up vote/accepted answer :) Also it will help your scoring and reputation on the site.

Comment: The only reason I didn't vote for your answer is because 15 of reputation is needed :(

Comment: Start accepting some answers for your questions, I believe you get +3 for each one you accept.